# how to determine direction of text in View?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need a directive witch determines the direction text and adds a class as "rtl" or "ltr", n order to assign attributes:

```
.rtl
{
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}
.ltr
{
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

how could I check the alignment of text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever you are working on text of an element in view, usually filters are more useful than directives:

```
app.filter('direction', function () {
  return function (text) {
    var rtlRegex = new RegExp('[\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC]+');
    var textalign = ( rtlRegex.test(text) ) ? 'rtl': 'ltr';
    return textalign;
  }
});
```

in the view

```
<p ng-class="(item.text | direction)">{{item.text}}</p>
```

And in CSS define:

```
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class/direction to the body element and then add this to your css file:

```
body.ltr .text-alignment {
  text-align: left !important;
}
body.rtl .text-alignment {
  text-align: right !important;
}

body.ltr .text-opposite-alignment {
  text-align: right !important;
}
body.rtl .text-opposite-alignment {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

so you add the class text-alignment whenever you need something aligned :)

we use it in our project and it works like a charm